# Playing multiple videos on the same player using html and php

Tags: php

I have my code for playing multiple videos in a single folder but I don't know where the error is

page1.php

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<title>Video tests</title>
</head>
<h5>Video List: </h5>
<ul>
<?php 
$filelist = scandir("videolibrary");
foreach($filelist as $key=>$video){
    if($key >1){
        echo '<li><a href="page2.php?video='.$key.'" >'.$video.'</a </li>';
    }
}
?>
</ul>
</br>
</body>
</html>
```

page2.php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
$current_video = $_GET['video'];
$filelist = scandir("videolibrary");
foreach($filelist as $key=>$video){
    if($key >1){
        if($key==$current_video){
            $current_video_src = $video;
            $next_video = $key+1;
            $previous_video = $key-1;
        }
    }
}
?>
<center>
<video id="MyVideo" width="720" height="480" controls autoplay>
<source src="videolibrary/<?php echo $current_video_src; ?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<a href="page2.php?video=<?php echo $previous_video; ?>" >Previous</a>
<a href="page2.php?video=<?php echo $next_video; ?>" >Next</a>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

looking forward for your help
I have updated my code, its opening the second page but the video isn't playing

Comment: what's the error you getting?

Comment: when I click a video from the list I have in my videolibrary, its not getting to the page2 where it should start playing.  Instead the link will add a #

Comment: is it works for one video?

Comment: none of the videos are playing

Comment: my aim is to play many videos on one player or page

Comment: why are you not playing videos on same page.

Comment: thus what I'm trying to do but I'm failing, can you help?

Comment: so you want to play and list videos on the same page? I will post my answer.

Comment: ok thanks, post the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is your full code as you want to do.

page1.php

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<title>Video tests</title>
</head>
<h5>Video List: </h5>
<ul>
<?php 
    $filelist = scandir("videolibrary");
    foreach($filelist as $key=>$video){
        if($key >1){
            echo '<li><a href="page2.php?video='.$key.'" >'.$video.'</a></li>';
        }
    }
?>
</ul>
</br>
</body>
</html>
```

page2.php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
    $current_video = $_GET['video'];
    $filelist = scandir("videolibrary");
    foreach($filelist as $key=>$video){
        if($key >1){
            if($key==$current_video){
                $current_video_src = $video;
                $next_video = $key+1;
                $previous_video = $key-1;
            }
        }
    }
?>
<center>
<video id="MyVideo" width="720" height="480" controls autoplay>
    <source src="videolibrary/<?php echo $current_video_src; ?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<a href="page2.php?video=<?php echo $previous_video; ?>" >Previous</a>
<a href="page2.php?video=<?php echo $next_video; ?>" >Next</a>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: let me try and I will tell you the result

Comment: man you are the best, now what if I want the list to appear in first page and the videos to play in a second page with a next and previous buttons

Comment: Yes you can also do this.

Comment: can you post the answer

Comment: when I click the video from the list its leading me to the page2 but the player is not playing, instead its saying: No video with supported format and MIME type found. Also the next and previous buttons are not there

Comment: Its working at my end. what is your video format. it will support only MP4, WebM, Ogg

Comment: update your latest code using in question, so that i can check

Comment: I have updated the code that I send at first you can see